# Confusion in one of the combinatorics/probability problem, with my approach for its solution.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, conditional-probability, factorial

> The only contents of a container are 10 disks that are each numbered
> with a different positive integer from 1 through 10, inclusive. If 4
> disks are to be selected one after the other, with each disk selected
> at random and without replacement, what is the probability that the
> range of the numbers on the disks selected is 7?

My approach: (Using the concept of conditional probability and combinatorics)

Possible ranges: **1-8, 2-9, 7-10** (Total 3)

Now, taking one range at a time, (say 1-8):
Hence, among the 4 disks to be selected, the probability of selecting the first disk will **1/10** (for **1**).
Similarly, **1** is selected, hence second place could be filled by **8**. Prob(second place is **1/9**).
Now, since out of range **1-8** 1 and 8 are selected, therefore we have only 6 choices (out of the remaining 8) for third place. Henceforth, only 5 choices (out of 7 choices) for fourth place.
Combining the probability of all 4 places, **(1/10)(1/9)(6/8)(5/7)**.

Now, the number in four places can be arranged in **4!** ways. Also, apart from the (1-8) range, there is also other two range of numbers.
Therefore, combining all, the required probability should be **(3)** x **(1/10)(1/9)(6/8)(5/7)** x **(4!)**.
But my answer is wrong. My answer is double of actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the glitch in your answer, **(3) x (1/10)(1/9)(6/8)(5/7) x (4!)**

**(6/8)(5/7)** implies that the two discs within the limiters are **already permuted**, so the **(4!)** needs to be replaced by **(4!/2!)**

If you had written **(2/10)(1/9)** for the limiters, the final factor would become **(4!)/(2!2!)**

It is because of such hidden snags that I prefer to use the safer route of combinations,  as @saulspatz has done.

Comment: Aye Sir, thanks for explaining it so well.

Comment: @saint_sharan: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure where you're double counting.  The method you've elected to use is rather confusing.

You've got all the pieces, but there's a simpler way to put them together.  There are, as you said, $3$ possible ranges.  There are $\binom62$ ways to choose $2$ numbers in the range other than the endpoints, so there are $3\binom62$ possible choices.  There are $\binom{10}4$ equiprobable ways to choose $4$ numbers, so the probability is $$\frac{3\binom62}{\binom{10}4}=\frac3{14}$$

**EDIT**

I'm having difficulty pinpointing your error.  As I said, the method is confusing.  I think the problem arises when you compute the probability of choosing $2$ numbers from the middle of the range.  You say the probability is $\frac{6\cdot5}{8\cdot7}$ which is true, but this incldues both the possibility of choosing $5$ and then $6$ and the possibility of choosing $6$ and then $5$.  When you then multiply by $4!$, I think you're doubling up.  I'm not $100\%$ certain though.

Comment: You are choosing just 4 numbers. Don't we have to consider the relative ordering of the picked 4 numbers also?

Comment: No.  The problem just says that the highest and lowest numbers we pick differ by $7$.  Where does order come into that?  If you want to consider order, you can multiply the numerator and denominator by $4!$, but that won't change the answer, of course.

Comment: Ok, got it. But, also could you please tell me where did my approach go wrong?